# Was my website hacked?

Tags: security, web

I am using a company called web-stat to watch for people visiting our website and noticed an entry page of "127​.0​.0​.1:4664/preview" rather than the url of the website or the url of a page.

Does this mean that someone has or is trying to hack our website?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not.  It looks like Google Desktop, but there's not enough information in your question to confidently say if it's an attack or not.  http://www.brighthub.com/computing/smb-security/articles/83577.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't really know enough about this. What other info should i put? Thanks again.

Comment: It's concerning that your webserver is seeing this particular request occur on it unless you are running a desktop on it, too.  You should be able to sniff the connection (with wireshark, tcpdump, or ngrep, depending on the OS), and see what the other side of the socket is.  If it's local, then netstat will identify the process.

Comment: No we're not running a desktop on it. it's just html text and links with embedded youtube. Their IP Address, country and ISP did come through as normal it was just the entry page that was odd being local.

Comment: I'm sure that Phillip Kinkade is correct that it was a Google Desktop search. Not sure how to close this and elect that Phillip had the answer.

Comment: I will add an answer to facilitate closing out the question, and hopefully this will help more people seeing port 4664 request on their servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests to 127.0.0.1:4664/preview are likely from Google Desktop.

[Security information about Google Desktop at SMB Security](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/smb-security/articles/83577.aspx)

To know for sure, you should inspect the TCP conversation and source endpoint to observe what exactly is making the requests.

Comment: Thanks Phillip. I'm happy to say it must have been google desktop. it hasn't happened again.